# Selecting records with most recent date for each 'order'

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have information in the format of the sample table below.  Each file can have multiple grades, I need to select the most recent grade (based on completion date) for each file.  If there is a file w/ the same completion dates, I would select the best grade (a being best and subsequent letters being a lesser grade).  This seems easy, but for some reason having a brain fart

Sample Table:

ID_PK File_No    Grade     Completion_Date

1     Smith      A         10/1/2010

2     Smith      C         9/25/2010

3     Davis      B         11/1/2010

4     Johnson    D         12/5/2010

5     Johnson    A         11/1/2010

6     Johnson    C         10/1/2010

7     Miller     X         9/1/2010

8     Miller     F         12/1/2010

9     Miller     D         10/1/2010

Ideal Results:

1     Smith      A         10/1/2010

3     Davis      B         11/1/2010

4     Johnson    D         12/5/2010

8     Miller     F         12/1/2010

Comment: Can you add an example of the expected output should be?

Comment: I didn't see the "Ideal Results" part.

Answer (score 2):

uSING WINDOWING FUNCTION IS MORE EFFICIENT and also simpler as

```
with cte AS(
select  '1' AS ID_no,'Smith' AS FILE_NO,'A' AS GRADE,
CAST('10/1/2010' AS DATE) AS CREATION_DATE
union all 
select '2','Smith','C','9/25/2010'
union all 
select '3','Davis','B','11/1/2010'
union all 
select '4','Johnson','D','12/5/2010'
union all 
select '5','Johnson','A','11/1/2010'
union all 
select '6','Johnson','C','10/1/2010'
union all 
select '7','Miller','X','9/1/2010'
union all 
select '8','Miller','F','12/1/2010'
union all 
select '9','Miller','D','10/1/2010')


SELECT X.ID_NO,X.FILE_NO,X.GRADE,X.CREATION_DATE FROM(
SELECT ID_NO,FILE_NO,GRADE,CREATION_DATE ,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY FILE_NO ORDER BY CREATION_DATE DESC,GRADE ASC ) AS RN
FROM CTE)AS X
WHERE X.RN=1
ORDER BY ID_NO
```

Answer (score 1):

try this (untested):

```
select max_grade.*
from `Sample Table` st
inner join (
  select File_No, max(Completion_Date) as Completion_Date
  from `Sample Table`
  group by File_No
) max_date on st.Completion_Date = max_date.CompletionDate
inner join (
  select File_No, Completion_Date, max(Grade) as Grade
  from `Sample Table`
  group by File_No, Completion_Date
) max_grade on st.File_No = max_grade.File_No and st.Completion_Date = max_grade.Completion_Date
```

Note that you may need to modify the syntax and table name for your particular DB.

Answer (score 0):

I created a table with your example data.  I tested the following query against the table and everything seem to work correctly and matched the example results.

```
SELECT 
    ID_PK,
    StudentGrade.File_No, 
    MIN(StudentGrade.Grade), 
    StudentGrade.Completion_Date
FROM
(
    SELECT File_No, MAX(Completion_Date) Completion_Date
    FROM StudentGrade
    GROUP BY File_No
) Student
INNER JOIN StudentGrade ON
    Student.File_No = StudentGrade.File_No 
    AND StudentGrade.Completion_Date = Student.Completion_Date
GROUP BY ID_PK, StudentGrade.File_No, StudentGrade.Completion_Date
ORDER BY ID_PK
```